# Python IDLE cannot open file, says "the open file operation failed to connect to the open and save panel service"

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, python-idle, macos-big-sur

just upgraded to a new MBP with an m1 pro chip. I'm encountering some weird issues trying to open files through IDLE. It throws an error saying "the open file operation failed to connect to the open and save panel service" I have tried reinstalling python, and when looking under the services settings for IDLE I couldn't find such a service. Both macOS Big Sur and macOS Monterrey have this issue. Otherwise, it seems like IDLE is performing as should.

Comment: You can use `ipython` instead of idle.

Comment: @WaketZheng This issue almost certainly has nothing to do with IDLE as it is Python, not IDLE nor ipython, that opens files.

Comment: You need to say how you got the message, the circumstances of the message, and what the complete error message and traceback is.  What 'file' you were trying to open?  How were you trying to open it?  When were you trying to open it?  When opening IDLE?  When trying to edit a file?  When running your program with an open(...) call?  The message quoted most likely came from macOS.  Please try to do the same thing without IDLE involved.

Comment: I am getting the same error, and I will add more detail on what I tried to do.   I installed python 3.10, in addition I attempted the same process with 3.8 using the universal2 installer.

Once python is installed, I open IDLE and it works as it should.   I can run commands in the console and whatnot. If I make a new file, and save it I get this message, if I click open it displays this (I don't get a chance to open a file).

I added idle, python launcher, and the python command to the full directory access with no effect.  I am running a new MBP with the M1Pro.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution but its not as good as I would like it to be.  At this time there is an error with the OS and Python that prevents it from working.  After reading from this (https://bugs.python.org/issue44828), I looked for the most current intel installer and installed 3.8.10.   While this isn't the solution of getting 3.10 working, it does get python working on your machine.

I no longer get the error.  I was also able to install pygame without going through homebrew, and it works great again.

Comment: The error is in the interaction between macOS Monterey and tcl/tk.  (Apple made unannounced changes; tk people are still trying to catch up.)  This affects Python's tk interface (tkinter), which affects IDLE as a tkinter user.